# From AWS RDS (SQL Server) to S3 bucket via lambda nodejs (streaming)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, aws-lambda

I am running a bit into trouble trying to downlaod some SQL Server data (aws rds) to an S3 bucket, passing via a csv-stringify conversion.

I am using a lambda function in nodejs 8.10

Since the downloaded records can be a few millions, I must use streams else *I would not be able to store the recordset in memory.

So I have a SQL request **req**, a **stringifier** and an s3-upload-streams stram called **uplaod**.

I also tried s3-stream instead and had the same result : I end up with a max memory error when the number of records exceeds about 200K.

I added some logging to try to understand what happens and discovered the problem is that the s3-upload-stream (same as the s3-stream) does not send the **part** until I close the stream, keeping everything in memory.

Here what I get from the log :

> 2019-03-19T16:09:31.995Z  query executed
>   2019-03-19T16:09:32.092Z    S3 Buffering is set to 5242880 x 1
>   2019-03-19T16:09:32.113Z    streams running
>   2019-03-19T16:09:37.933Z    Processed records : 10000 Available memory :  70750208
>   2019-03-19T16:09:40.494Z    Processed records : 20000 Available memory : 64368640
>   2019-03-19T16:09:43.492Z    Processed records : 30000 Available memory : 78753792
>   2019-03-19T16:09:45.652Z    Processed records : 40000 Available memory : 75481088
>   2019-03-19T16:09:47.952Z    Processed records : 50000 Available memory : 72622080
>   2019-03-19T16:09:50.853Z    Processed records : 60000 Available memory : 68972544
>   2019-03-19T16:09:53.013Z    Processed records : 70000 Available memory : 67604480
>   2019-03-19T16:09:55.193Z    Processed records : 80000 Available memory : 64204800
>   2019-03-19T16:09:57.933Z    Processed records : 90000 Available memory : 80928768
>   2019-03-19T16:10:00.152Z    Processed records : 100000 Available memory : 79167488
>   2019-03-19T16:10:02.392Z    Processed records : 110000 Available memory : 76013568
>   2019-03-19T16:10:05.292Z    Processed records : 120000 Available memory : 73478144
>   2019-03-19T16:10:07.572Z    Processed records : 130000 Available memory : 73641984
>   2019-03-19T16:10:10.852Z    Processed records : 140000 Available memory : 72503296
>   2019-03-19T16:10:14.053Z    Processed records : 150000 Available memory : 69713920
>   2019-03-19T16:10:14.074Z    stringifier done
>   2019-03-19T16:10:16.012Z    writing s3 part
>   2019-03-19T16:10:16.013Z    { ETag: '"a4e3140f5d17fab9b3ccff9561a05730"',
>     PartNumber: 1,
>     receivedSize: 5242880,
>     uploadedSize: 5242880 }
>   2019-03-19T16:10:16.204Z    writing s3 part
>   2019-03-19T16:10:16.204Z    { ETag: '"30c90f1880190bea1fc9b5e1e7a1286d"',
>     PartNumber: 2,
>     receivedSize: 5530146,
>     uploadedSize: 5530146 }
>   2019-03-19T16:10:16.401Z    { ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256',
>     Location: 'https://someplaceinmys3bucket',
>     Bucket: 'mybucket',
>     Key: 'foldername/lambdaTest.csv',
>     ETag: '"553d7927911f047633d04503f92a9281-2"' }
>   END RequestId: 
>   REPORT RequestId: Duration: 45686.58 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 117 MB

As you can see I can download about 10000 records every 2.5 seconds, BUT the s3 stream calls the part event only AFTER I close the stringify.

Here is my code setup :

```
req.stream = true; 
req.query(sql);    

if (__DEBUG) console.log("query executed");
upload = s3Stream.upload(s3params);

console.log("S3 Buffering is set to "+s3BufLen+" x "+s3ConcurrentBuffers);
upload.concurrentParts(s3ConcurrentBuffers); // limit to x buffers
upload.on('part', function (details) {
            if (__DEBUG){
                console.log("writing s3 part");
                console.log(details);
             }
 });

upload.on('uploaded', function (details) {
                    console.log(details);
                    mssql.close();
                    callback(null,details);
});

var stringifier = stringify(csvOptions);

stringifier.on('finish', function(){
                          if (__DEBUG) console.log("stringifier done");
                          upload.end();
                     });

stringifier.on('readable', function()
                          {
                            let row;
                            while(row = stringifier.read())
                            {
                               if (__DEBUG && (++processed % 10000 == 0)) console.log("Processed records : "+processed+
                                  " Available memory : "+ os.freemem());
                                upload.write(row); 
                            }
                          });

req.pipe(stringifier); //.pipe(upload);
```

I temporarily "unpiped" the upload stream and added the stringifier.on handlers to debug better the process.

What I was expecting was that the **part** event of the upload stream was called at every 5MB block encountered, instead all the blocks are apparently flushed AFTER I close the stream.

Note that I also forced the  upload.concurrentParts(...) to 1, to no avail.

**UPDATE:**

I saw that the s3-upload-streams module is considered deprecated and it suggests to use s3.upload instead (from the AWS SDK), which indeed improved the things -it uses way less memory-, but did not solve completely the problem for me, memory consumption still increases with the number of parts.

This is how I modified my code :

```
    var upload = new stream.PassThrough(), 
    s3options = {partSize: s3BufLen, queueSize: s3ConcurrentBuffers};

    s3params.Body = upload;

    s3.upload(s3params, s3options, function(err, data) {
              console.log(err, data);
              mssql.close();
              callback(err,data);
    });

    req.pipe(stringifier).pipe(upload);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: this works locally for me, but the upload is simply not happening for me in the cloud - any ideas on what might be going on for me?